# What was the die size of the 6581 SID?

Tags: commodore-64, mos-6581, sid

The MOS 6581 SID, the original version of the sound chip in the Commodore 64, was according to Wikipedia, 'produced in 7-micrometer technology to gain a high yield; the state of the art at the time was 6-micrometer technologies.'

At that process size, area was a limiting factor, though not much of one; the chip didn't end up with every feature Bob Yannes wanted, but a Commodore manager famously pointed out to him, with only a little hyperbole, that the chip was ten times better than anything else out there, and twenty times better than it needed to be.

What was the actual die size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [a series of stepped die shots](ftp://retronn.de/chips/sid_6581r2/original/), and knowing that the steps were 0.5mm one way and 0.45mm the other way, we can estimate the die area as about 27.2 mm².