# What percentage of the SID was control versus voices?

Tags: commodore-64, sid, mos-6581

I'm interested in specifics of the design and manufacturing of the SID, the sound chip of the Commodore 64.

There is a good die photo here http://www.visual6502.org/images/8580/Commodore_8580_die_20x_top_1500w.png, but it's not annotated; I don't know which part is what. Does anyone have any idea?

A previous question talked about the die size. [What was the die size of the 6581 SID?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13405/what-was-the-die-size-of-the-6581-sid)

Descriptions of the features it provides are available e.g. on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6581

- Three separately programmable independent audio oscillators (8 octave range, approximately 16 - 4000 Hz)
- Four different waveforms per audio oscillator (sawtooth, triangle, pulse, noise)[6]
- One multi mode filter featuring low-pass, high-pass and band-pass outputs with 6 dB/oct (bandpass) or 12 dB/octave (lowpass/highpass) rolloff. The different filter modes are sometimes combined to produce additional timbres, for instance a notch-reject filter.
- Three attack/decay/sustain/release (ADSR) volume controls, one for each audio oscillator
- Three ring modulators[6]
- Oscillator sync for each audio oscillator
- Two 8-bit analog-to-digital converters (typically used for game control paddles, but later also used for a mouse)
- External audio input (for sound mixing with external signal sources)
- Random number/modulation generator

In particular, I'm interested in how much of the area was devoted to envelope control features versus the voices that actually generate the sound. The distinction being that the former are essentially luxuries that do some of the work for the programmer, but could be done in software by updating control registers at the end of each video frame, whereas the latter could not be done in software without completely tying up the CPU, i.e. not concurrently with updating video in a game.

From the above feature list, the audio oscillators are the things that generate the actual sound. Not sure what the ring modulators are. The ADSR volume controls are definitely control features.

What percentage of the chip was spent on the control features versus the oscillators versus ancillary features like the analog-to-digital converters, external audio input and random number generator?

Comment: According to http://sidmusic.org/sid/sidtech2.html the first five attack times are: 2 ms, 8 ms, 16 ms, 24 ms, 38 ms, and they all sound different. Not doable with a vblank playroutine, even if it was possible to control channel volume directly (which isn't possible). From what I can see, the SID seems to have been made by a musician and not an engineer who read about music in a book. :)

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Your observation is correct, SID chip was designed by Bob Yannes, an electronic engineer and an electronic music hobbyist, who had experience on music synthesis. Later he founded Ensoniq.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I stand corrected! That is interesting to know, thanks.

Comment: @rwallace It's not just the envelopes, but there's oscillator sync, ring modulation and a resonant multimode filter. I suppose you don't know what to do with any of those? From a musician's point of view, the SID was designed to be a "synth", not a sound generator like the AY-3-8910. Add to that the possibility of having a computer program control all the facilities of the synth. The 6502 + SID combo puts the C64 in a different category as a musical instrument, compared to machines with sound generators. Add a MIDI input and you can have something like the MSSIAH  https://mssiah.com/